# Using sleep() to avoid hitting rate limit not working

Tags: php, api, limit, endpoint, rate

I'm hitting my rate limit on an API I'm using and I'm confused because the method I used to prevent this seems like it should definitely work, but it's not working 100% of the time.  I have this line before every API call that's supposed to call a function that checks if I'm close to my limit and if I am, then sleep just long enough to reset my hit count.  Like this:

```
if (isset($http_response_header)) {rateLimit($http_response_header);} 
file_get_contents($endpointURL);
```

Here's the function:

```
function rateLimit($header)
{
// get hit count from $header

// $count[0] is how many hits per second
// I have a limit of 20 per second

// $count[1] is how many hits per 2 minutes
// I have a limit of 100 per 2 minutes

if ($count[0] == 19) {sleep(1); return;}
if ($count[1] == 99) {sleep(120); return;}
}
```

It's supposed to sleep 1 second if I've made the maximum number of calls per second, and sleep two minutes if I've made the maximum calls per 2 minutes.  Is there something wrong with my code, or must it be something wrong with the API incorrectly limiting me?

Here is the entire `rateLimit` function, since someone wanted to know how I was parsing it:

```
function rateLimit($header)
{
$pos1 = strpos($header[7], ' ') + 1;
$pos2 = strpos($header[7], ':', $pos1);
$count[0] = substr($header[7], $pos1, ($pos2 - $pos1));

$pos1 = strpos($header[7], ',') + 1;
$pos2 = strpos($header[7], ':', $pos1);
$count[1] = substr($header[7], $pos1, ($pos2 - $pos1));

if ($count[0] == 18) {sleep(1); return;}
if ($count[1] == 98) {sleep(120); return;}
}
```

Comment: RTM: [http_response_header](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) does not return an array of ints, please show how your parsing that. Also its not a good idea to sleep, instead just return false and use rateLimit function as a check for the condition.

Comment: do you have to hit the api that often? up to 20 hits/s sounds harsh. it just screams "caching" to me, but you might have some live update stuff going on..?

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone I updated my question with the entire function showing how I parsed it.  I'm using sleep to postpone the API call instead of skipping it because I need every call to work, no matter how long it takes.  Why doesn't it work when I type @ before your name? I'm using a development key for the Riot Games (League of Legends) API that's severely limited because it's just for testing purposes.  They don't accept applications for better keys for a week or so but I'm working with what I have until then.

Comment: @MelerLawler if you're on a development key and using this for dev only then just cache the response and use your local copy. No need to hit the api for the same document time after time

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `$count` defined as array in your `rateLimit` function, so you are probably getting an undefined index warning and that's breaking your code.

So either do this

```
function rateLimit($header)
{
    $count = [];    

    $pos1 = strpos($header[7], ' ') + 1;
    $pos2 = strpos($header[7], ':', $pos1);
    $count[0] = substr($header[7], $pos1, ($pos2 - $pos1));

    $pos1 = strpos($header[7], ',') + 1;
    $pos2 = strpos($header[7], ':', $pos1);
    $count[1] = substr($header[7], $pos1, ($pos2 - $pos1));

    if ($count[0] == 18) {sleep(1); return;}
    if ($count[1] == 98) {sleep(120); return;}
}
```

or this

```
function rateLimit($header)
{
    $pos1 = strpos($header[7], ' ') + 1;
    $pos2 = strpos($header[7], ':', $pos1);

    $pos1 = strpos($header[7], ',') + 1;
    $pos2 = strpos($header[7], ':', $pos1);

    if (substr($header[7], $pos1, ($pos2 - $pos1)) == 18) {sleep(1); return;}
    if (substr($header[7], $pos1, ($pos2 - $pos1)) == 98) {sleep(120); return;}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these solutions worked (I can confirm the problem was not failing to declare the array because using a test header it worked fine).  It seems my `rateLimit` function must work because the logic is simple and I tested different possibilities for the value of `$header[7]` and they are all parsed correctly.  `$header[7]` looks like this: `X-App-Rate-Limit-Count: x:1,y:120` where x and y are my hit counts for per second and per 2 minutes, respectively.  Maybe the API is incorrectly limiting me.

Comment: Nope, turns out the API is limiting me only when I hit the limit.  Not sure why my code doesn't make me `sleep` before that happens.

Comment: I found out erasing the line `if ($count[0] == 19) {sleep(1); return;}` makes it sleep if `$count[1] == 99`. Gonna figure out why this is and report back.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I think both counts were hitting their max on the same API call but the `rateLimit` function was returning after sleeping for only one second, to reset the first count, but this was ignoring that the second count needed to be reset too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be I was always looking in key `7` for the string telling me my hit count but it was sometimes in a different key.